# PHPMyAdmin Timeout on File Upload invalidating MYSQL password and losing access (Using XAMPP)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to upload a large file to PHPMYADMIN and my script timed out. When this happened I get the following errors when trying to use the "reupload your script to resume" button.

1)MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.

2)Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

3) phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I went into the config.inc.php file on my machine and my password is still what it was originally set as, but when I go through the command line and type in my password to access MYSQL im denied access.

Why have I been locked out of MYSQL because of the fileupload going wrong on PHPMYADMIN? Has anyone had this happen before and know a solution.

I've reinstalled and tried again when another timeout happened and I lost access to MYSQL and PHPMYADMIN once again. My next plan is to disable the timeout and reinstall for a third time and hope I don't get another timeout in the future but this seems like a ridiculous workaround because my credentials should NOT be invalidated because of a large file upload timing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your *.sql* file is rather large, it may be a better option to import it from [command line](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/open-a-command-prompt-window):

```
C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -p DB_NAME < dump.sql
```

(Assuming Windows, default XAMPP location and MySQL config - change the values accordingly.)

Edit: Importing large SQL dumps using phpMyAdmin definitely shouldn't break anything. It would just timeout or take very long. I've never had this happen to me and I've been using XAMPP for years.